# Can correlation be negative for a couple of series but positive for the average of those series?

Tags: correlation

Say I have a couple of equal-length data series, X1, X2, X3, and Y. I also create a series Xm which is simply the mean for X1 X2 and X3.

Can it be that the correlation between Y and all of X1, X2, and X3 is negative, but the correlation between Y and Xm is positive, or vice versa? If so, how, and what does that tell you about your data, if anything.

Context: I saw this occur in some personal data analysis I was doing today, and it's making me doubt the correctness of my analysis/calculations. But I also feel it can be a counter-intuitive result of how standard deviation works in practice.

Answer (score 1):

No, thanks to the (bi)linearity of covariance.

$\textrm{Cov}(X_m,Y)=\textrm{Cov}\left(\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3}3,Y\right)=\frac13\textrm{Cov}(X_1,Y) + \frac13\textrm{Cov}(X_2,Y)+\frac13\textrm{Cov}(X_3,Y)$

so if $\textrm{Cov}(X_1,Y) , \textrm{Cov}(X_2,Y) , \textrm{Cov}(X_3,Y)$ all have the same sign, then $\textrm{Cov}(X_m,Y)$ must also have that sign.